# Efficient way to concatenate the names of the 7 highest columns per row?

Tags: r

This code will take the names of the 7 highest columns in the first row and then paste them together in a new variable. I want to do this for every row in a dataset that's 1M rows long and I cannot do a loop in a reasonable amount of time. What's the most efficient way to do this in R?

Thanks

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$names = ""
mtcars[1,]$names = paste(names(sort(mtcars[1,1:11]))[5:11],collapse = " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how efficient this is in terms of memory, but it's reasonably quick and all base R:

```
maxnrow <- function(data, n) {
  rowidx <- 1:nrow(data)
  out <- vector(mode="list", n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    out[[i]] <- max.col(data, "first")
    data[ cbind(rowidx, out[[i]]) ] <- -Inf
  }
  do.call(paste, lapply( out, function(x) names(data)[x] ))
}


mtcars2 <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),1e6,replace=TRUE),]

system.time( maxnrow(mtcars2, 7) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.02    0.58   10.62
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` might be a good approach for memory efficiency.

The idea here is to reshape the data into long format, sort the values for each car, then select the top 7 for each group.

You can the use the result however you want, including `paste`ing the results to make a new variable

```
library(data.table)

dt_mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = T)

## melt the data into long form so we can sort it by one column
dt_mtcars <- melt(dt_mtcars, id.vars = "rn")

## order by group (rowname), and pick the top 7
setorder(dt_mtcars, rn, -value)
dt <- dt_mtcars[ dt_mtcars[, .I[c(1:7)], by = rn ]$V1 ]

## create a new column, consisting of the names of the 'rownames' of those top 7
dt[, paste0(variable, collapse = " "), by = rn]

                 rn                             V1
 1:         AMC Javelin   disp hp qsec mpg cyl wt drat
 2:  Cadillac Fleetwood   disp hp qsec mpg cyl wt carb
 3:          Camaro Z28   disp hp qsec mpg cyl carb wt
 4:   Chrysler Imperial   disp hp qsec mpg cyl wt carb
 5:          Datsun 710 disp hp mpg qsec cyl gear drat
 ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

`sapply(1:nrow(mtcars), 
      function(i) paste(names(sort(mtcars[i,1:11]))[5:11],collapse = " "))`